# Printing vector graphics from Metal on OSX

Tags: objective-c, macos, metal

Is it possible to output vector graphics from the Metal API?

Especially in regards to rendering fonts/text.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The trouble with using signed-distance fields (as described in Chris Green's 2007 paper ["Improved Alpha-Tested Magnification for Vector Textures and Special Effects"](http://www.valvesoftware.com/publications/2007/SIGGRAPH2007_AlphaTestedMagnification.pdf)) for this is that they require you to rasterize the glyphs at a finite resolution and reconstruct the glyph outline in a shader, which can lead to reduced fidelity. There have been some strong advances in this field lately, such as [Viktor Chlumský's work on using multi-channel SDF textures](https://github.com/Chlumsky/msdfgen) to maintain sharp edges.

There has also been a lot of work in the last decade on using GPUs to render implicit curves more directly, much of it derived from Loop & Blinn's "Resolution Independent Curve Rendering using Programmable Graphics Hardware" (2005), which was also written up in [GPU Gems 3](http://http.developer.nvidia.com/GPUGems3/gpugems3_ch25.html). The most robust implementation of glyph rendering that does GPU-only rasterization that I know of is the one in [GLyphy](https://vimeo.com/83732058). Will Dobbie has written an impressive [WebGL demo](http://wdobbie.com/pdf/) that uploads glyph outline parameters as a texture and also rasterizes purely on the GPU, briefly described [here](http://wdobbie.com/post/gpu-text-rendering-with-vector-textures/).

Also, I'd be remiss if I didn't mention [Matt Deslaurier's work](https://mattdesl.svbtle.com/material-design-on-the-gpu) in this area. You can [view some of his demos here](https://github.com/mattdesl/fontpath#demos).

In conclusion, my post/book (mentioned in Marius' answer) show a basic implementation of SDF font rendering in Metal, but any of the above-listed techniques should be fairly straightforward to implement in Metal once you understand the ideas, and most of them will produce better results.